# Why is Angular say that loggedInUser!: string; is not assignable to type string?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-authentication

**This is the exact error**:
Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
(property) NavbarComponent.loggedInUser: string

Here is my code:

```
/* navbar-component-ts */
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { AuthService } from 'src/app/services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FlashMessagesService } from 'flash-messages-angular';
import { Client } from '../../models/Client';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
/* Properties */
isLoggedIn!: boolean;
loggedInUser!: string;
showRegister!: boolean;


  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    private flashMessage: FlashMessagesService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.getAuth().subscribe(auth => {
      if(auth) { 
        this.isLoggedIn = true;
        this.loggedInUser = auth.email;
      }else {
        this.isLoggedIn= false;
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link)](https://tsplay.dev/WJ8q5N), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration for you `loggedInUser` is fine.

I think the problem comes from `auth.email`, try this:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authService.getAuth().subscribe(auth => {
        if (auth) {
            this.isLoggedIn = true;
            const userLoggedIn = auth?.email;
            this.loggedInUser = userLoggedIn || 'no-email';
        } else {
            this.isLoggedIn = false;
        }
    });
}
```

I believe the property `email` from your `auth` object can be `string` or `null`, if it is `null`, then, as the error message says, the value `null` is not assignable to a variable type of `string`

Also, you can do this as well, although, personally, I don't use it

```
 loggedInUser!: string | null;
```

`loggedInUser` can hold `string` and `null` values.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I've been trying so hard all day to figure it out and thanks for the tip too!  loggedInUser!: string | null;

Answer (score 1):

just modify declartion

```
loggedInUser!: string;
```

to be

```
loggedInUser: string;
```